# How to exclude folders in range with gitignore

Tags: git, directory, gitignore

I have this folder called `90`, but the name could change into `91`, `92` ecc.
How can i ignore all the possibile folders that will be created?

I tried this in the `.gitignore`

```
**[90-100]/
```

But it didn't seem to work. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: `.gitignore` ignores **lexicographically**, not numerically.

Comment: so? it's impossible to do? @phd

Comment: would it be a solution to create a directory that include all these numerical folders and then ignore this entire directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matching is done characterwise. You want just `*[0-9]/` to match any folder name ending with at least one digit, or you can get more explicit by specifying multiple patterns like `*[^0-9][1-9][0-9]/` for folder name having an exactly two-digit trailing number.

Comment: in my example notice that i use `**[90-100]/`, so i'm supposed to do `***[0-9]/` ?

Comment: `[90-100]` matches characters 9, 0-1, 0 or 0.